# How do I store this array to multiple variables?

Tags: php, arrays

Hi how do I store this array to two different variables instead of echo??

```
$countries = array();
foreach ($my_data as $node)
{
    foreach($node->getElementsByTagName('a') as $href)
    {
        preg_match('/([0-9\.\%]+)/',$node->nodeValue, $match);
        $countries[trim($href->nodeValue)] = $match[0]; 
    }
}    

foreach ($countries as $country => $percent) echo str_replace("Â","",(strip_tags($country))) . ' - ' . str_replace("Â","",(strip_tags($percent)));
```

This will output

```
USA - 75%
UK - 65%
AU - 56%
UAE - 52%
```

and so on
What I am looking is I need this array to store in multiple variable for example

```
$datac = USA,UK,AU,UAE

$datap = 75%,65%,56%,52%
```

like that any idea?

Comment: Your replacing is destroying your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$datac = array();
$datap = array();

foreach($countries as $country => $percent) {
    $datac[] = str_replace("Â","",(strip_tags($country)));
    $datap[] = str_replace("Â","",(strip_tags($percent)));
}
```

If you want them as strings, you can just do:

```
$datac = implode(',', $datac);
$datap = implode(',', $datap);
```

Reference: [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)